# CSS box model pushing element lower on the page

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to fix a bit of test html to work with opera/chrome. It's using the [holygrail box model from matt levine](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail).

In IE and firefox it looks like

[correct layout http://img187.imageshack.us/img187/4049/writedn1.jpg](http://img187.imageshack.us/img187/4049/writedn1.jpg)

In chrome, opera and safari it pushes the sidebar element down. I've played with the margin and paddings but it still doesn't work. am I missing something?

[wrong layout http://img73.imageshack.us/img73/6279/wrongpx8.jpg](http://img73.imageshack.us/img73/6279/wrongpx8.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
          min-width:500px;
          padding: 0 106px;
        }
        #center, #left, #right,#sidebar,#main {
          position:relative;
          float:left;
        }
        #center {
          width:100%;
          background:#CCC;
        }
        #left {
          width:106px;
          margin-left: -100%;
          right:106px;
          background:#C0C;
        }
        #right {
          width:106px;
          margin-right: -106px;
          background:#CC0;
        }
        #header{
          width:100%;
          background:#0CC;
        }
        #footer{
          width:100%;
          background:#A0E;
          clear:both;
        }
        #content{
          padding-right:330px;
          background:#F00;
        }
        #main{
          width:100%;
          padding:5px 15px;
        }
        #sidebar{
          width:300px;
          margin-right: -300px;
          background:#33C;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="center">
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="main">
      copy
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
      side
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">footer</div>
</div>
<div id="left">
left
</div>
<div id="right">
right
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work in both Safari and Firefox (haven't tested the other browsers yet)

Change this:

```css
#content{
      padding-right:300px;
      background:#F00;
}
#main{
      padding:5px 15px;
      width: 100%;
      margin-right: -30px;
}
```

Dunno why this works any better than what you have above, but it does :)

If you're looking for premade grid-based layouts, though, I'd suggest [BlueprintCSS](http://www.blueprintcss.org/). I've used it for a bunch of projects, and it's really easy-to-use. It is a fixed layout (not fluid like yours), so that may be a deal-breaker.

Comment: Be wary of using anything from sites with 750px fixed width content.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know that min-width doesn't work on the BODY tag, at least in certain versions of IE (I thought it worked in Firefox, though).  You might want to try putting your entire page in a DIV tag and setting min-width on that.